# UnityIAP Subscription Purchase

Tags: unity

Basically I want to setup UnityIAP for implementation of weekly or monthly subscription for apple store game. I completely read following article given by Unity:

[Integrating Unity IAP In Your Game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game?playlist=17123)

After this I become aware with actual implementation but i have following questions arise:

1. how we can get information about subscription already purchased by this user?
2. how we track time for auto renewable subscription purchase?

Please give me some information about this.